# Using cart rules (coupons) in addition to catalog rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

When running a catalog rule we are finding that customers can still use coupons that get added in addition to the catalog discount already applied. We have the discard subsequent rules turned on for all pricing rules, and have changed the priorities for the cart rules to be after the catalog rule. Does anyone know if these modules talk to each other, or had any other issues with running a catalog rule where coupons can still be applied?

Comment: Hi Katie please edit your question to add what version of Magento you are using. That would help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not omit products that has special price (or has a catalog rule) from your shopping cart price rule. You can remove catalog price rule and make another shopping cart price rule for your sale products. Then you can set priorities.